# jQuery: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .Marketing&Communications

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery to add a class name to an element, but when the class name contains special characters like '&', or '/', it throws the error seen below:

```
function cleanString(string) {
  if (string) {
    var cleanString = string.replace(/\s+/ig, "");
    return cleanString;
  }
  else {
    return "Uncategorized";
  }
}

var team = nullCheck(_data[i].title)
var teamCleanString = cleanString(team);
$('#jobs-container .jobs-teams').append(
    '<a href="#" class="btn '+teamCleanString+'">'+team+'</a>'
  );
}
```

Produces this:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .Marketing&Communications
```

Comment: What is the code of the `cleanString` function? What line of your code returns the error?

Comment: @litel Sorry, added the function to the OP.

Comment: You can change the `\s+` in your `replace` regex to `\W+` if you want to remove the `&`.

Comment: @litel That did it, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There are certain characters that have functionality that are not valid for naming CSS selectors without escaping.

[Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors)

You can use these special characters in naming if you perform proper escaping.

https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes

Try using `.Marketing\&Communications`